# Gallery pics re-sized when seeing from android

Tags: android, wordpress, image, size, gallery

I’m quite a newbie around here so this kinda feel like I’m learning sanscrit. Thrilling and overwhelming at the same time.

Anyway, the thing is I'm using wordpress at my laptop and I'm sttrugling at keeping my pics at the size expected when I switch to android. They look totally fine on the laptop preview for the phone, but on the real world they're basically turning into a thumbnail. I attach a picture of [expectation versus reality](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aTdK7.png)

I apologize in advance because I suspect this is part of the ABC of programming; I don't even know if I should be uploading my pics with a particular size. I promise I'm training to become a proper padawan, and 'll appreciate any feedback.

Thank you so much for your time, and have a great day!

Comment: `They look totally fine on the laptop preview for the phone` What do you mean with a 'laptop preview' ?

Comment: And if you have pictures on your laptop then how can they be displayed on your phone?

Comment: When editing a page on my laptop using wordpress, I have an option to "pre-visualize" how it will be seen on the phone version. It looks fine there.

Comment: They are displayed on my phone as everything else does; I'm creating my website from the laptop. I can't imagine doing it from anywhere else, my phone is prehistoric

Comment: This is my web project https://jacarandaterapias.es/
Its phone version is not working properly. That would be the dilemma, cuting short.

Comment: So there is a website on the internet with images and you display that website on an Android phone then something is different. Which Android app is displaying your website?

Comment: I had a look at your site but how would i conclude that sizes are not normal? And how do you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are starting with Wordpress, best thing to do is to work with themes supported by Elementor & one that allows you to modify the design for desktop, tablet, & mobile versions separately.
-Select 'Edit with Elementor'
-select the section with these six pictures. in the '#Edit Section' box at the right, you will see three options- layout/content, style, advanced.
-Select 'Advanced' and scroll down till the bottom section.
-Select the 3rd last option, 'Responsive'. From here you can hide the mentioned section for mobile.
[It would look something like the attached picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kDpq5.png)

DO BEAR IN MIND THAT I HAVE ADDED SAME BUTTON TWICE - the button at the left is visible to site visitors using desktop/tablet. At the right part, you can see same button blurred. That's 'cause I hid it from Desktop & Tab.

Similarly, you too have to add section with pictures again to show in mobile only.
[For that, find and click on Responsive icon & select Mobile.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8vRJX.png)
Decorate the section just the way you want and do not forget to hide it from PC & Tab.